# Angular: when using ng-include, number variable become NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, declaration, prototypal-inheritance, angularjs-ng-include

I have a problem when i try to fragment my html with ng-include:

This is what my index.html page looks like when it works (prix=price, TVA=tax):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title> TVA </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
                <input ng-model="tva" placeholder="TVA" /><br />
                <input ng-model="prix" placeholder="Prix" />
                <select ng-model="taxe">
                    <option>HT</option>
                    <option>TTC</option>
                </select>
                <button id="btn" ng-click="calcul()">Calculer</button>
                <p>{{ total }}</p>
           </div>
     </div>
     <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The script.js :

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.calcul = function() {
        if ($scope.taxe == "TTC") {
            $scope.total = parseInt($scope.prix) + $scope.prix * $scope.tva /100;
        } else if($scope.taxe == "HT") {
            $scope.total = 1/(1+$scope.tva/100)*$scope.prix;
        }
    };
}]);
```

So this works, the result is an number (the price with or without tax).

When I use the ng-include like this:

```
<div>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <div ng-include="'tva.html'"></div>
        <input ng-model="prix" placeholder="Prix" />
        <select ng-model="taxe">
            <option>HT</option>
            <option>TTC</option>
        </select>
        <button id="btn" ng-click="calcul()">Calculer</button>
        <p>{{ total }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only tried to replace the first input with a new HTML page.

The tva.html :

```
<input ng-model="tva" placeholder="TVA" /><br />
```

Now the results show "NaN" (I put those codes on a server so that I can check online). Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Josh Beam Answered & explained `ng-include` creates a child scope on creating the DOM. I'd suggest you to use `dot rule` in angular that will follow [**prototypal inheritance**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) on that object and you object value will access in child scope.

Now your object structure will changed to `$scope.model={};` and this model will have all the input values. like all will become like `model.prix`, `model.taxe` & `model.tva` so that the prototypal inheritance will follow.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'tva.html'"></div>
    <br />
    <input ng-model="model.prix" placeholder="Prix" />
    <select ng-model="model.taxe">
      <option>HT</option>
      <option>TTC</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btn" ng-click="calcul()">Calculer</button>
    <p>{{ total }}</p>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
    $scope.calcul = function() {
        if ($scope.model.taxe == "TTC") {
            $scope.total = parseInt($scope.model.prix) + $scope.model.prix * $scope.model.tva /100;
        } else if($scope.model.taxe == "HT") {
            $scope.total = 1/(1+$scope.model.tva/100)*$scope.model.prix;
        }
    };
}]);
```

**tva.html**

```
<input ng-model="model.tva" placeholder="TVA" /><br />
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0fV0CpaXSveR1KpTcAsr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: don't use `ng-include` in this instance.

**Long answer**: `ng-include` creates a new child scope, so `ng-model` inside the `ng-include` isn't `appCtrl`'s `TVA`. I don't see a reason here to use `ng-include` anyway, your code is fine without it.

So basically you're getting `NaN` (not a number) because `$scope.TVA` is never set when using the `ng-include`... you're attempting to multiply an undefined variable by another number, which returns `NaN`:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is the *`ng-include`* creates a new scope under the scope when the HTML was included, but you can access to the parent scope by specifying *`$parent`*

```
<input ng-model="$parent.tva" placeholder="TVA" /><br />
```

A better approach is give an **alias** to your controller, so it will be clear semantically to children controllers accessing to a specific parent.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl as vmMain">
    <div ng-include="'tva.html'"></div>
```

... and in the other file:

```
<input ng-model="vmMain.tva" placeholder="TVA" /><br />
```