# Angularjs:ng model is not accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-template in angularjs

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-wig/views/ng-wig.html">
<div class="ng-wig">
........
</div>
<script>
```

and i have a textarea using this ng-template.

```
<textarea ng-wig="content" ng-model="contents"></textarea>
```

but this ng-model cannot be accessed inside the controller.
please help.

Comment: What is the exact code, don't post just snippets

Answer (score 2):

As you are loading your textarea template inside `ng-include`, if you look at `ng-include` directive you will see that it does create a new scope which is [**prototypically inherited**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) from the parent scope.

If you use any scope variable which are declared in controller won't be accessible inside the include div. In order to get the controller variable accessible inside `ng-include` the you must declare it as `object` like `$scope.model= {}` then you should declare the properties in it. like  `ng-mode="model.contents"`

**Markup**

```
<textarea ng-wig="model.content" ng-model="model.contents"></textarea>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Here you can find [**similar answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012456/2435473)

---

There are several approaches apart from above by which you could solve this issue.

The other way around would be, you could use controller as approach in that way you can avoid. In that you need to use `this` inside a controller & use controller alias while showing variable on html like `vm.contents` here

**Makrup**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
   <div ng-include="'ng-wig/views/ng-wig.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**Textarea**

```
<textarea ng-wig="content" ng-model="vm.contents"></textarea>
```

---

Also you could point to the parent scope of `ng-include` which is nothing but controller scope just by doing `$parent` in your `ng-model`, this case your ng-model would be `$parent.contents`

**Textarea**

```
<textarea ng-wig="$parent.content" ng-model="$parent.contents"></textarea>
```

**Note**

> Don't use this approach, use the 1st one which is more preferable.

Comment: can you elaborate.ur answer?

Comment: @NishamMahsin sure give.. me a few minutes

Comment: @NishamMahsin do look at my edit..That would help you..Thanks :)

Comment: thanks.now can i access vm.contents from parent controller?

Comment: @NishamMahsin yes you could..anyway its not parent controller you should call it as parent scope.. I would prefer you use 1st approach which is using prototypal inheritance

Comment: where i have to put `<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">` . since idont have ng-include i guess. i am using angular template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81570/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-nisham-mahsin).